# labels on a stacked density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, stacked-chart, density-plot

I'm generating a stacked density plot:

```r
ggplot(data=tydy_rawdata, aes(x=timepoint, y=tpm, group=fct_inorder(names), 
    fill=fct_inorder(names))) +
         geom_density(position="fill",
                      stat="identity") +
         scale_fill_manual(values = rev(mycolors))
```

plot :
[image]

I would like to add label on each curve (or at least the top 3 or 4) basing on the "names" displayed on the right.

I'm trying adding geom_text but the result is this :

```r
gplot(data=tydy_rawdata, aes(x=timepoint, y=tpm, group=fct_inorder(names), 
    fill=fct_inorder(names))) +
         geom_density(position="fill",
                      stat="identity") +
         geom_text(aes(label=names)) +
         scale_fill_manual(values = rev(mycolors))
```

plot :

[image]

Are there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your chart is a stacked area chart, i.e. `geom_density` with `stat="identity"` is equal to `geom_area`. Second, when adding labels via `geom_text` you have to take account of the `position` argument. As you use `position="fill"` for your density/area chart you also have to do the same for `geom_text`.

As you provided no example data I created my own to make your issue reproducible:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

set.seed(123)

tydy_rawdata <- data.frame(
  names = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 6),
  timepoint = factor(seq(6)),
  tpm = runif(6 * 10, 0, 80)
)

ggplot(data = tydy_rawdata, aes(
  x = timepoint, y = tpm,
  group = fct_inorder(names), fill = fct_inorder(names)
)) +
  geom_area(
    position = "fill",
    color = "black"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = names), position = "fill")
```

[image]